# Easier accessible?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, comparative-constructions, adverbial-phrases

Is it correct to say “It is easier accessible”?
I think the correct way is to say

> “It is accessible more easily”
>   or
>   “It is easier to access something”.

I think that we cannot describe an adjective (accessible) by another adjective. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You should use an adverb to modify an adjective.

Your two alternatives are both good. The other option is:

> It is **more easily** accessible.